# C++ generic container with linked list

Tags: c++, algorithm, generics, data-structures, containers

I want to design a generic container for use with linked lists (for example).
I tried using `void*` as an element but this fails when I provide the following.

```
list.insert(5);
list.insert("Hello");
```

If I allocate the member on the heap and pass the address it works, but how can I handle the case of using stack variables in the example above?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: I tried using memcpy, but in case of literals are passed I have no address to copy. and how can i give the variable back as void is not a type in C it is alway void*

Comment: I guess the error message would be "syntax error", as this is tagged C, and C has no support for member functions.

Comment: Are templates out of bounds? i.e.: `List<int>` versus `List<char*>`

Comment: @Lundin: The above code is valid syntax in C, provided `list` is a struct instance and `list.insert` is a function pointer.

Comment: @Sven Yeah... well... but nobody writes code like that in C for ADTs. Anyway, the question is retagged to C++ now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the size in bytes somehow.

```
int x = 5;
insert (&x, sizeof(int));
insert ("Hello", 6);
```

etc.

The insert method could then for example look like this:

```
void insert (void* data, size_t size)
{
  node_t node = malloc ...

  node.data = malloc ...
  node.size = size;

  memcpy(node.data, data, size);
}
```

Comment: @Jeremy Oops, that's indeed a bug. Thank you, I will edit it.

Comment: And now this is magically tagged C++ suddenly. Then a better solution may be to use templates, and not void*.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I would use [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/any/s02.html) for this.

Answer (score 1):

... could simply try to overload the insert function...

`List::insert( int i ){}`
`List::insert( char* i ){}`

etc....

Comment: This works for primitives. What about generic objects? Passing in void* would need a size value too.

Comment: @Jeremy - or a fully templated insert `template<class T> List::insert(const T&);`. At least it would know `sizeof(T)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a generic container, you have no choice but to create a dummy object containing the scalar value (OMG-why do I have to think of java?) and insert that. You could add special insert_int, insert_char, ... methods how do the copying on their own. This way you had also no trouble with literals and stack variables.